Decimal to IEEE754 single precision Conversion in emu8086 Assembly
I need to create a program in emu8086 that meets the following requirements:

Program description:

Write an assembly language program using the 8086 that converts a number from decimal format to its IEEE754 single precision format.
The program must comply with the following features:
1.1 Input:
The number must be entered using function 0Ah of interrupt 21h.
The format of the number before converting it is as follows:
±65535.999 (Remember that you have to enter this number using function 0Ah).
For example: +5589.014
1.2 Output:
The program must display the converted number in two different formats (it is recommended to use a menu to ask the user which option they want to display):
Binary (Continuing with the previous example):
Sign: 0
Exponent: 10001011
Mantisa: 01011101010100000011101
Hexadecimal: 45AEA81D
You can use function 02 of interrupt 21h to display the number.
1.3 Important notes:
Use functions from interrupts 21h and 10h (to change the screen or color).
Implement VALIDATIONS when the number is entered.
1.4 Additional information:
I don't know much about emu8086 assembly language, and I would appreciate it if someone could help me with my program.
Thank you in advance.
This is my humble attempt to start.
.data
inputBuffer db 13 ; Tamano maximo para +-65535.999 + CR
db ? ; Caracteres realmente leídos por 0Ah
db 13 dup(?) ; Aqui se almacena el input del usuario

sign db 0 ; 0 para positivo, 1 para negativo
integerPart dw 0 ; Parte entera del número
decimalPart dw 0 ; Parte decimal del número, asumiendo maximo 3 dígitos significativos
menuOption db 0 ; Opción seleccionada en el menu

promptMenu db "Selecciona una opcion:", 13, 10, "1. Binario", 13, 10, "2. Hexadecimal", 13, 10, "$"
promptInput db "Introduce el numero en formato +-65535.999: $"
errorMsg db "Entrada invalida, intenta nuevamente.", 13, 10, "$"  

maxValue dw 65535 ; Valor maximo permitido para la parte entera
maxDecimal dw 999 ; Valor maximo para la parte decimal

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Mostrar mensaje para ingresar el número
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, promptInput
    int 21h

    ; Preparar y llamar a la función 0Ah para leer la entrada
    lea dx, inputBuffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Llamar a la función para validar y procesar la entrada
    call validateAndProcessInput

    ; Continuar con el resto del programa...
    jmp showMenu
    


proceedConversion:
    ; Aquí iria el código para proceder según la opción seleccionada
    ; ...

finish:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

showMenu:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, promptMenu
    int 21h
    call getMenuOption
    ret

getMenuOption:
    mov ah, 01h ; Leer caracter
    int 21h ; Retorna el caracter en AL
    sub al, '0' ; Convertir de ASCII a valor numérico
    cmp al, 1
    jl invalidOption ; Si es menor que 1, opción inválida
    cmp al, 2
    jg invalidOption ; Si es mayor que 2, opción inválida

    mov menuOption, al ; Guardar la opción seleccionada
    jmp proceedConversion ; Continuar a la conversión

invalidOption:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, errorMsg
    int 21h
    jmp showMenu ; Mostrar el menu nuevamente

end start


This website is for Q&A that ideally provides answers of lasting value to both the original poster and future knowledge seekers.  Try asking such a question.

Your "humble attempt to start" looks like just whoever gave you the assignment provided for you. There is nothing inside the proceedConversion block. Asking homework questions is ok, if you show some actual effort to solve the problem and get stuck at a concrete point. Please read the [tour] and [ask].
